# stop auto page reload and only rebuild ui in angular

Tags: angular, livereload

I need to update only scss compilation part without reloading the entire page when I save any scss file.

I have tried to search but not getting any idea how to do this.

I tried passing `--live-reload false` option inside `ng serve` that angular provides as a default but this does not refresh anything.

So any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be looking for 'Hot Module Replacement':

https://dev.to/iamscottcab/using-hot-module-replacement-in-angular-11-mji

I've had some luck using it in the past but rarely use it myself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Although not mentioned regarding how to enable the hmr in angular, thanks for suggesting hmr.